# Why simple closed curves are dense in $\mathcal{PML}_0(S)$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I have another question about laminations on surfaces. As usual let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of homotopy classes of simple closed curves in $S$ and $\mathcal{PML}_0(S)$ be the set of projective classes of measured geodesic laminations on a surface $S$. I know there is an injective map

$i:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow \mathcal{PML}_0(S)$

which associates to $[\gamma]$ the lamination with support the geodesic representative and with measure a Dirac measure of any weight.

My question is the following: **How can I prove that $i(\mathcal{S})$ is dense in $\mathcal{PML}_0(S)$?** Maybe someone can point me out a reference..

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [McMullen's 2005 note](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/275/05/html/home/course/course.pdf)s, Cor 2.4 Another proof can be found in Thurston's notes (chapter 8).

Comment: Thank you, but I can not find a proof of Cor 2.4 on the reference "Combinatorics of train tracks" by Penner and Harer.. Can you help me out with that? Also, is there a proof which doesn't use train tracks?

Comment: @user61720 I am not sure I understand. Are you saying you can't find the proof of theorem 1.6.5 (or whatever) in HP?

Comment: Also, why don't you like train-tracks?

Comment: I am saying I can not find proof of Cor 2.4 in HP. By Thurston's notes you mean the book FLP? If so, chapter eight is about measured foliations.. how is this connected?

Comment: @user61720 Thurston's notes http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/

Comment: @j.c. precisely

Answer (score 0):

The space $\mathcal{MF}$ of measured foliations admits a set of coordinate charts by train tracks. Each weight on a train track corresponds to a measured foliation, and a rational weight correponds to a weighted multi-curve. Rational weights are dense and it's easy to prove that each weighted multi-curve can be approxiated by a sequence of simple closed curves.